# Filtering comment by date range in Views

Tags: views, datetime

I have created a view to filter comments by date range. For date range i am using between operator.

- View type : Comment
- Date : comment created (default field)

**Issue :** When i am trying to filter comment from 2015-11-01 to 2015-11-15

i am getting result from 2015-11-01 to 2015-11-14 only.

what i am missing ? may be some help me ?

Comment: You also can choose the `between or equal to` option. So, `between` excludes the outer value, where `between or equal to` includes the outer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views uses in between operator i.e. [BETWEEN min AND max](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) expression.

[image]

This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max). Now the query that views create for date is:

`(comment.created BETWEEN 1446336000 AND 1447545600)`

Search for unix time value of [1447545600](http://www.unixtimestamp.org/1447545600)

The problem is with the date **2015-11-15**, this is treated as 2015-11-15 00:00:00. So 2015-11-15 11:12:13 won't be included. Hope you get my point.

Comment: Means there is a bug in date range filter in Views. How can i resolve this ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: simply use the preferred date format (CCYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS): 2015-11-15 23:59:59

Comment: And no its not a bug. This is how mysql works. Just be precise. Added link for BETWEEN ... AND ... operator.