# Exposed date filter adds a timezone offset in query

Tags: 8, views, datetime

In Drupal 8, when creating a view with an exposed filter on a Date field (which is in `date only` mode), the resulting query removes some hours based on my timezone.

I'm in the UTC+2 timezone, so a date filter of `2016-04-20` creates a query of `DATE_FORMAT('2016-04-19T22:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d')`. And so, none of the nodes I want are displayed...

How to avoid that?

[image: wrong query for an exposed date filter because of timezones]

Comment: Just check once http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198186/filtering-comment-by-date-range-in-views

Comment: @visabhishek In this case it's not a `between` but a `equals` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The following helps when rendering views programmatically:

```
$event_date_time = new \DateTime($query->get('date'), new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$event_date_time->modify('+1 day');
$event_date = $event_date_time->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'))->format('Ymd');

$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('events');
$view->setArguments([$event_date]);
$output['events'] = $view->preview();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow. It seems the core [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2825127#comment-14774592) has not yet resolved.

That happens because:
`\Drupal\datetime\Plugin\views\filter\Date`

```
  protected function opSimple($field) {
    $timezone = $this->getTimezone();
    $origin_offset = $this->getOffset($this->value['value'], $timezone);
    //...
  }

  protected function getTimezone() {
    return $this->dateFormat === DateTimeItemInterface::DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT
      ? DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE
      : date_default_timezone_get();
  }
```

calls `$this->getTimezone()` and `$this->dateFormat` in my case is `Y` (I selected "Year" granularity within filter configuration).

Then `getTimezone` returns default server timezone. That's because `DateTimeItemInterface::DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT` is `Y-m-d` to get UTC timezone.

Meantime, I use the next trick (In my case I need a filter by year) with adding custom exposed form element validate callback.

```php
function kb9_issue_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void {
  if ($form['#id'] === 'views-exposed-someview-page-1') {
    $currentYear = (int) date('Y');
    $years = array_reverse(range(
      MIN_YEAR,
      $currentYear - 1
    ));

    $options = ['now' => $currentYear] + array_combine($years, $years);

    if (isset($form['year'])) {
      $form['year'] = [
        '#type' => 'select2',
        '#options' => $options,
        '#select2' => [
          'placeholder' => t('Select year'),
        ],
        '#prefix' => '<div class="year-container">',
      ];

      unset($form['year']['#process']);
      array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'mymodule_validate_year_filter');
    }
}

function mymodule_validate_year_filter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $year = $form_state->getValue('year') ?? FALSE;

  // If user deleted value from GET parameter (e.g year=''),
  // then fill it with current year.
  if (empty($year)) {
    $form_state->setValue('year', 'now');
  }
  else {
    // Make year a bit bigger than default timezone offset.
    // Alternativelly, you can calculate needed ofset.
    // And ofcause you need validate year format before :)
    $form_state->setValue('year', $year . '-1-2');
  }
}
```